# MS access query divide one text field by another and store result in another text filed

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have three columns in my MS Access table with names 'Column1' ,'Column2' and 'Result.'These three columns are text fields. Now, I need a query to divide first column with second column and store the result into third column.

EX : Column1/Column2= Result.

Here , Main problem is the three fields are text fields. Can anyone please help me on this.

Thanks & Regards
madhu.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the values to a number and then back.  Something like:

```
select cstr(cdbl(column1) / cdbl(column2)) as Result
```

However, I would *strongly* advise you to store numbers as numbers and not as strings.  Storing them as strings will just make your code less efficient and harder to debug.

EDIT:

As an update, this looks like:

```
update table
    set Result = cstr(cdbl(column1) / cdbl(column2));
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for your reply."update tablename set Result= cstr(cdbl(column1) / cdbl(column2))" . will this query work for update colum3 ?

Comment: @MadhuSudhanReddy . . . The `update` will update `Result`, not `column3`, unless you include that as well in the statement.

Comment: Sorry, in my case this 'Result' is the 'column3'. I mean the name of column3 is Result